# How to center bootstrap input field properly?

Tags: css

I am trying to center a bootstrap google style input field. However, I am not sure how I can do it properly without hacks or breaking the style.

I have tried adding a #center div around the input, adding auto margin left and right, with no luck.

I can use margin-right hacks, but they will break the style and aren't a proper solution.

HTML:

```
<body>
<dic id="center">
<div class="styled-input">
  <input type="text" required />
  <label>Email</label>
  <span></span>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#center{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.page-wrap {
    max-width: 75rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

input:focus ~ label, textarea:focus ~ label, input:valid ~ label, textarea:valid ~ label {
    font-size: 0.75em;
    color: #8e44ad;
    top: -0.9rem;
    transition: all 0.125s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0, 0.03, 1);
}

.styled-input {
    float: left;
    width: 33.3333%;
    margin: 2rem 0 1rem;
    position: relative;
}
.styled-input label {
    color: #999;
    padding: 1rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0, 0.03, 1);
    pointer-events: none;
}
.styled-input.wide {
    width: 100%;
}

input, textarea {
    padding: 1rem 1rem;
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
input ~ span, textarea ~ span {
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 3px;
    background: #8e44ad;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 0.125s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0, 0.03, 1);
}
input:focus, textarea:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
input:focus ~ span, textarea:focus ~ span {
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 0.125s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0, 0.03, 1);
}

textarea {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 15em;
}

body{
  background-color: gainsboro;
  }
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ce39fp2h/

As you can see, the input is stuck to the left. How can I center it properly?

Comment: You need to fix a misspelling for div in the fiddle.  Doesn't fix it but would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following rule, instead of your current rule:

```
.styled-input {
    width: 33.3333%;
    margin: 2rem auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

> **demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/ce39fp2h/4/

Comment: Brilliant! Good job.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you need, but I did this,

```
<body>
<div id="row">
<div class="col-md-12 styled-input">
  <input type="text" required />
  <label>Email</label>
  <span></span>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

And removed:

```
float: left;
width: 33.3333%;
```

Answer (score 0):

look it this demo. https://jsfiddle.net/ce39fp2h/3/

I only chage that in your code:

Delete  and place that id in next  such:

```
<body><div id="center" class="styled-input"><input type="text" required /><label>Email</label><span></span></div></body>
```

In css i change that:

```
#center {
margin: auto;
width: 50%;
padding: 10px;}
```

and delete float: left in styled-input class.